# Wordpress page permalink error

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Hello my name is vaibhav and my site is www.tricky-photoshop.com
I am having a peculiar problem with my website. I have created an "about" page for my website and it was working fine few days ago.

But now with the same URL, my theme is showing "`page not found`". For example suppose I have set the URL of "about" page as "`abc.com/about`" and then publish the page but when i type "`abc.com/about`" in URL box in my Google Chrome then my website shows "`page not found`".

**Screenshots**

1. https://www.box.com/s/zcjm532yzavc4rdyyxki (note that the URL is " /about")
2. https://www.box.com/s/9jjfnsdv6i79glf7aa2r (with same URL theme is showing "page not found")

**Same thing happens with all the pages in my website (except home) but with posts its working fine.**

Thank You in advance

Comment: Have you installed any new plugins lately? Did you try to go to **Settings > Permalinks**? Also it seems like your posts are only using their post name for the permalinks. So I guess, that WordPress thinks it's looking for a post with a slug `about`, instead of a page. Can you try changing your permalinks settings to include the category name for instance?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is toggling permalinks to default, and then back to post title.

Go to `Settings>Permalink Settings` select `default`, save, and then select `post name` or whatever setting you had before. That's sorted out some strange issues for me in the past. That will be useless if you are putting the wrong url into the `permalink` field, so make sure that is correct first.